# My React app is rendering my image's URL as url('undefined');

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, jsx

So here is my JSX code.

```
<div class="propertie-item set-bg" style="background-image: url('https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/housessoldeasily.com/img/bg.jpg');"><div class="sale-notic">FOR SALE</div><div class="propertie-info text-white"><div class="info-warp"><h5>176 Kingsberry, Dr Anderson</h5><p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Rochester, NY 14626</p></div><div class="price">$1,777,000</div></div></div>
```

However, when I run my app, the image isn't being loaded. When I inspect element the element shows:

```
<div class="propertie-item set-bg" style="background-image: url('undefined');"><div class="sale-notic">FOR SALE</div><div class="propertie-info text-white"><div class="info-warp"><h5>176 Kingsberry, Dr Anderson</h5><p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Rochester, NY 14626</p></div><div class="price">$1,777,000</div></div></div>
```

Not sure why it is doing this as it's an exact path and it exists.

Comment: The issue is with your component code, link that.

Comment: https://github.com/jfny/custom-everything/tree/master/client/v1

Comment: You need to be more specific, with the bit that's causing you problem

Comment: The static html version of this website renders the div's background image just fine, but I'm trying to convert this static site into a react app so instead of doing ------ style="background-image: url('img/propertie/1.jpg');" ------- I need to do ----- style={ { backgroundImage: "url('https://example.com')" } } ---- but it renders as url('undefined')

Comment: So what is the component code that creates the JSX?

Comment: Currently in the process of breaking it down into smaller components ---- https://github.com/jfny/custom-everything/blob/master/client/v1/src/components/Home.js

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, calling quotes inside other quotes causes them to escape. So I've wrapped the image link inside `''` rather than `""` so it will render the string inside properly.

```
<div class="propertie-item set-bg" style="background-image: url('https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/housessoldeasily.com/img/bg.jpg');"><div class="sale-notic">FOR SALE</div><div class="propertie-info text-white"><div class="info-warp"><h5>176 Kingsberry, Dr Anderson</h5><p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Rochester, NY 14626</p></div><div class="price">$1,777,000</div></div></div>
```

If you're looking to convert your existing static site into a ReactJS site, then I would recommend reading this [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Comment: Sorry, my actual app does use single quotes otherwise your right, it would signify the end of the string. I accidentally put double quotes when I was editing the post for stackoverflow. But the problem still persists.

Comment: ah, well the issue is with your component code, link that

Comment: This link shows a pic of how it should render vs how it does render -----https://imgur.com/a/hJnBD39